# App crash on setAPNSToken method using FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-analytics

I was implementing Firebase and noticed that in latest releases FirebaseAnalytics was not included, therefore I downgraded as suggested in other posts and had FirebaseAnalytics (5.2.0) installed.

But unfortunately, the program crashes on this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {    
      [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeProd];   
}
```

with the following error:

> [FIRInstanceID setAPNSToken:type:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Update firebase to the latest version(FirebaseAnalytics change to Analytics), and change InstanceID to this:

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)

import Firebase
Analytics.logEvent(fir_event, parameters: dictionary_fir) //This is the new method
```

Comment: what is its equivalent in objective c

Comment: [[Messaging messaging] setAPNSToken: deviceToken type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod];

[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:"fir_event" parameters:"dictionary_fir"];